# MikTex Installation problems

Tags: miktex2.9

I just attempted to update MikTex. The Win 7 installation seemingly went fine. However, when I attempted to open TexWorks directly it did not respond. I went to task manager and saw that MikTex-TexWorks was running. I ended that process and then tried to open TexWorks by double clicking a .tex file I had earlier created. Same result, it did not respond but MikTex-TexWorks was running. What to do???

Comment: This is the complete error message:

can't read "::active_cls": no such variable
can't read "::active_cls": no such variable
    while executing
"if {[winfo class $c] in $::active_cls} {
        $c state !disabled
      }"
    (procedure "total_dis_enable" line 21)
    invoked from within
"total_dis_enable 1 "
    (procedure "read_line" line 26)
    invoked from within
"read_line"